# Change window size on virtual box after installing debian Jesse

Tags: window, debian

I installed Debian-jesse on Virtualbox. However, the max screen size is 1024 x 768. I have a larger monitor that can have a larger window size. Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can increase that? If I drag the window edge, a white band comes around the Debian window, but I can't use it. I installed dkms as suggested by other threads, but that doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the `contrib` section in your apt sources in your jessie guest system. You might need to add `contrib` to the respective line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, like so

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib
```

Then, as root, run

```
apt update
apt install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

and reboot the guest system (restarting its X server may also suffice).

If you have manually configured your X server in the guest system, an idea would be to move `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` out of the way, if it exists. Or, more bluntly, to purge xserver-xorg, reinstall, and then reinstall the guest additions.

Comment: Thanks. I installed it exactly as you mentioned, but now after reboot, virtual box does not start. It goes to the login window, and then everything hangs. I can't click on anything. When I go to recovery mode, it boots. Nothing in /var/log/Xorg. However when I do startX, it starts the server, brings up the desktop, but then hangs. I got into recovery mode again, and try removing virtualbox-guest-x11, but the problem is still there. A google search, brings up forums, which say that some kernel components got overwritten. Any thoughts?

Comment: I did this on a fresh and uncustomised Debian jessie install in a virtual machine today, and it went flawlessly. Sorry it seems to be something non-standard at your end. Kernel components got overwritten? Sounds scary. [This](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/virtualbox-guest-x11/filelist) is the list of files that should have been installed in your guest system.

Comment: Thanks Johannes. I decided to use VMware instead. Lack of time to debug this.